# asp.net - load CSS file dynamically renders but doesn't load the CSS file

Tags: asp.net

in my ASP.NET app, I'm trying to add a CSS reference dynamically (with intelligent caching on the client).

My code renders to the browser correctly, but it doesn't load the CSS file.
I have to put the link in my markup explicitly for the CSS file to load, but it won't load when in code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Styles/Site.css"));
        HtmlGenericControl link = new HtmlGenericControl("LINK");
        link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
        link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
        link.Attributes.Add("href", "~/Styles/Site.css?t=" + fi.CreationTime.Ticks.ToString());
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
    }
}
```

This seems really simple.  Not sure why it isn't working.

NOTE: the attending the fileinfo ticks has no effect on the behavior.  It renders fine but doesn't load regardless of appending the file information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resolve the client URL for the stylesheet and then it will work:

```
link.Attributes.Add("href", ResolveClientUrl("~/Styles/Site.css?t=" + fi.CreationTime.Ticks));
```

Comment: awesome!  Thank you!  I am curious though: the rendered code looks the same.  Do you know why this makes a difference?  Is it about the way ASP.NET/IIS loads the dynamic files like CSS files?

Comment: @pearcewg without the ResolveClientUtl() call it still has the ~/ in the markup <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/Site.css?t=634534960310240974"></LINK> whereas it's resolved otherwise <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Site.css?t=634534960310240974"></LINK>